# nordvpn whitelisting 2 subnet LAN hierarchy

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, routing, subnet

I have a network setup like this:

**Ubuntu Laptop** (192.168.1.157) --> **Router B** (192.168.1.1) --> **Router A** (192.168.0.1) --> **Internet**

and

**CIFS NAS drive** (192.168.0.50) --> **Router A** (192.168.0.1).

When vpn disconnected, laptop can ping any 192.168.0.* devices and it can access the NAS drive.

On the laptop, I've created nordvpn whitelist for all local addresses:

```
> nordvpn whitelist add subnet 192.168.0.0/16
```

The resulting setting:

```
> nordvpn settings
Technology: NORDLYNX
Firewall: enabled
Firewall Mark: 0xe1f1
Routing: enabled
Analytics: enabled
Kill Switch: disabled
Threat Protection Lite: disabled
Notify: disabled
Auto-connect: disabled
IPv6: disabled
Meshnet: disabled
DNS: disabled
Whitelisted subnets:
        192.168.0.0/16
```

So now, when it is connected to VPN, the Laptop can ping

- 192.168.1.* devices
- Internet addresses (1.1.1.1, [www.google.com](http://www.google.com))
- But NOT to 192.168.0.*

> **Versions**
>
> **OS** Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
>
> **Kernel** 5.19.0-32-generic
>
> **NordVPN** 3.15.5

What can I do to get my laptop see the NAS drive?

Note 1: I know I can just move the NAS drive to same subnet 192.168.1.0/24 to get it working but I'm curious what's stopping the traffic to the upper level of a local network.

Note 2: I've already chatted to NordVPN tech support and didn't reach a solution

Comment: Can you share the output of `ip route` before and after establishing the VPN connection? Do you have a static route for 192.168.1.0/24 on router A (pointed at router B)?

Comment: here's the output:
❯ ip route
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlp1s0 proto dhcp metric 20600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp1s0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.157 metric 600 

I don't have any static routes configured (I don't even know how)